# How do draw 3D arrows?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, 3d

I'm using Illustrator CS2 to create some graphics. In one of my graphics I'd like to use a "3D" arrow lying on the ground as shown in the following example:

[image]

I want to draw arrows just like in the image shown. Best thing would be an effect "3D arrow" so I can scale it afterwards without adapting it... How can I do this? Do I need to use another program or are there special arrows I can load into Illustrator?

Comment: You could draw them using basic principles of perspective. Though an easier solution is to probably use the SKEW transform tool.

Comment: The arrows in your example are isometric — not '3D'.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is more than one single way to accomplish this. However, by far the simplest way is to utilize the Symbols Library.

### Create a Single Arrow

1. Open up the Symbols palette: **Window > Symbol** *(Shift + Ctl/Cmd + F11)*
2. From the Symbols palette menu, choose **Open Symbol Library > Arrows**
   [image: Open Symbol Library - Arrows]
3. Next, choose the appropriate arrow from the **Arrows palette** to add to your **Symbols palette**. Or skip to **4**
   [image: Arrows Palette]
4. Drag the arrow you want directly onto your canvas.
5. Making sure you have your arrow-symbol selected, choose **Object > Expand...**
6. Uncheck **Fill** and click **OK**
   [image: Expand Object]
7. Again, making sure you have the arrow selected, choose **Object > Ungroup** *(Shift + Ctrl/Cmd + G)*
8. Deselect the arrow *(Shift + Left Click)*. It should still look like the arrow is selected; however, all you have selected now is the bounding box that was created with the symbol. Press **delete** to discard the bounding box.

### Duplicate, Mirror, Unite

Next, we're going to make a duplicate of this arrow that mirrors it then unite the two together to form the double-headed arrow.

1. By far the easiest way to do this is to press *Alt + Shift + Left Arrow Key*. Now you should have a perfectly aligned duplicate arrow to the left of the original.
2. Right-click on the duplicate, and choose **Transform > Reflect...** or go to **Object > Transform > Reflect...**
   [image: Transform - Reflect]
3. From the **Rotation menu**, choose **Vertical** then press **OK**
   [image: Reflect - Vertical]
4. Now that we have mirror arrows, we want to unite them together to create one arrow: Move your arrows a fair distance apart while still overlapping.
5. Open your **Pathfinder palette**: **Window > Pathfinder** *(Shift + Ctrl/Cmd + F9)*
6. Click *Unite**
   [image: Unite]
7. You now have a completed double-headed arrow.
8. Using the **Direct Selection Tool**, you can now select the 7 points of one arrow, then, while holding down **Shift**, you can click on one of the points and move that arrow-head as far from the other as you need.
   [image: Move Arrow Head]

### Create Perspective & Optional 3D Effect

Before you move or rotate the arrow into the position desired. We're going to add the perspective to it to complete the effect.

1. Right-click on the arrow and choose **Transform > Shear...** or **Object > Transform > Shear...**
2. From the **Shear menu**, check the **Preview** box to help figure out what angle would best suite your needs. Based on the image provided, I chose roughly a **20 degree shear angle**.
   [image: Shear]
3. Now that this is complete, you can move, rotate, duplicate, reflect, etc, your arrow(s) into position.

#### Optional 3D

1. Now that your arrows are in place... *(I changed mine to red to show you mine are new as opposed to the yellow arrows)*
   [image: Arrows in place]
   ... we can use the **Effect > 3D > Extrude & Bevel...** menu.
2. From this menu, select the options that work best for you. For the **Positioning** I chose **10,0,0**; and for the **Extrude & Bevel** I chose and **Extrude Depth** of **10pt**.
   [image: Extrude & Bevel]

That's it! You now have 3D arrows!

Comment: I wish I could give you +10 just for all that effort. :)